# UnityEventTools AddPersistantListener With Dynamic Type

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, generics, dynamic-programming

Sorry if the following is confusing...

QUESTION:

How do I go about adding a new persistent unity event action to a `UnityEvent` from a generic type with a dynamic entry?

EXAMPLES:

I have the following function:

```
public static void SetUnityEvent<T>(T targetEvent, UnityEventEntry entry) where T : UnityEventBase
{
  ...
}
```

and inside that function from the `UnityEventEntry` object I'm trying to add a new action to the UnityEvent but I'm not sure how to do that with a dynamic type:

```
UnityEventTools.AddObjectPersistentListener(
   targetEvent,
   unityaction,
   <what do I add here>
);
```

This may not be the right thing to do at all. However, this is what I mean by a `dynamic` parameter:

[image]

How would I add a new action item into a `UnityEvent` that is including that dynamic parameter?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

HOW I'M CURRENT WRITING IT:

```
public static void SetUnityEvent<T>(T targetEvent, UnityEventEntry entry) where T : UnityEventBase
{
    UnityAction void_execute = (UnityAction)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(UnityAction), entry.component, entry.function);
    UnityEventTools.AddObjectPersistentListener(
       targetEvent,
       void_execute,
       <What do i add>?
    );
}
```

IMPORTANT NOTE:

If I write it like:

```
UnityEventTools.AddVoidPersistentListener(
                    targetEvent,
                    void_execute
                );
```

That will work, but that's for voids and will not include that dynamic parameter. Not sure how else to do it.

Also trying to add it like:

```
UnityEventTools.AddPersistentListener(
  targetEvent as UnityEvent,
  void_execute
);
```

Will result in `targetEvent` being a `null`.

Comment: Found this: https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Editor/Mono/Inspector/UnityEventDrawer.cs

Which has helped me to identity that I'm having issues with: `PersistentListenerMode.EventDefined`. Everything else has a simple add method. This type does not. Not sure what I should be adding here.

Comment: Based on the previous link I think I'm super close to an answer. Hope to have one tomorrow or the next day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it! Only 2 weeks worth of digging and coding to get up to this point. Simple when you think about it but hard when this is 100% undocumented anywhere on the web it seems like.

Here is what you want to do.

NOTE: The following will be defined like the following:

```
target = GameObject target of the same component you're putting this event on
targetComponent = The Component you're putting this event on
unityEventName = The name of the UnityEvent on the "targetComponent"
```

My script also takes advantage of the `entry` item which is a class that is initialized like the following:

```
public GameObject target = null;
public Component component = null;
public MethodInfo function = null;
public object parameter = null;
public int callState = -1;
public PersistentListenerMode mode = PersistentListenerMode.Void;
```

1. Setup a "dummy" event like the following:

```
MethodInfo tmpFunc = GetMethodInfo(target, "SetActive", PersistentListenerMode.Bool);
UnityAction<bool> tmp_event_execute = System.Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(UnityAction<bool>), entry.target, tmpFunc) as UnityAction<bool>;
UnityEventTools.AddBoolPersistentListener(
    targetEvent,
    tmp_event_execute,
    false
);
```

This can be any event, it doesn't matter. I just use `SetActive` with the GameObject because it seems to be a universal thing you can do with anything.

2. Modify that "dummy" listener entry using `SerializedProperties`:

```
// Get the listener entry to modify
SerializedObject so = new SerializedObject(targetComponent);
SerializedProperty persistentCalls = so.FindProperty(unityEventName).FindPropertyRelative("m_PersistentCalls.m_Calls");
SerializedProperty listenerEntry = persistantCalls.GetArrayElementAtIndex(persistantCalls.arraySize - 1);

// Get the individual items on that listener entry
SerializedProperty listener_Target = listenerEntry.FindPropertyRelative("m_Target");
SerializedProperty listener_CallState = listenerEntry.FindPropertyRelative("m_CallState");
SerializedProperty listener_FunctionName = listenerEntry.FindPropertyRelative("m_MethodName");
SerializedProperty listener_Mode = listenerEntry.FindPropertyRelative("m_Mode");
SerializedProperty listener_Arg = listenerEntry.FindPropertyRelative("m_Arguments");

// Modify the entry with the new target values (Notice for dynamic events I don't include an argument/parameter)
listener_Target.objectReferenceValue = (entry.component == null) ? entry.target : (UnityEngine.Object)entry.component;
listener_FunctionName.stringValue = entry.function.Name;
listener_Mode.enumValueIndex = (int)entry.mode;

listenerEntry.serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
```

Then boom! After doing that you now have an added persistant listener with a dynamic variable included all done via an Editor script. Also because you modify the "dummy" listener in place there is nothing to cleanup afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Example in the context of localization to set the text mesh pro text field from a event.

```
    public static MonoBehaviour SetupForLocalization(TextMeshProUGUI target)
    {
        var comp = Undo.AddComponent(target.gameObject, typeof(LocalizeStringEvent)) as LocalizeStringEvent;
        var setStringMethod = target.GetType().GetProperty("text").GetSetMethod();
        var methodDelegate = System.Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(UnityAction<string>), target, setStringMethod) as UnityAction<string>;
        Events.UnityEventTools.AddPersistentListener(comp.OnUpdateString, methodDelegate);
        comp.OnUpdateString.SetPersistentListenerState(0, UnityEventCallState.EditorAndRuntime);
        return comp;
    }
```